# Regex With Asp.net Mvc StringLength Attribute

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

I have Asp.net mvc application where on submit form i am using Regex and StringLength Attribute to check string.Scenario is that i allow some kind of codes but their lengths are different. My Class item regex and attribute  is here:`

```
[StringLength(13,ErrorMessage="Allowed 13 or 12 Characters",MinimumLength=12)]      
[RegularExpression("^(01|04|05|06|pt|pT|Pt|PT|fg|fG|Fg|FG)[0-9]*(FR|fr|Fr|fR)?$", ErrorMessage = "Entered Format Is Incorrect")]
public string BarCode { get; set; }
```

the problem is that barcodes **FG**,**01,04,06** are **12** in length when **PT** codes length must be **13**. ussualy users use **PT** codes 90%..
sometimes they insert **12 length PT** codes and its mistake.
can i have 2 regex same time? and can i validate length for particular codes in regex?.i think [StringLength(13,ErrorMessage="Allowed 13 or 12 } atrribute is not what i need here..

Comment: You cannot have 2 `[RegularExpression]` attributes, but you can have a single regex that allows bar codes containing `FG` to contain 12 characters and those containing `PT` to containing 13 characters (using an `|`), and delete the `[StringLength]` attribute

Comment: Try [something like this](https://regex101.com/r/xx02kT/1), but note that `FR` at the end that is optional will not count here.

Comment: Perhaps, [`^(?:(?:[Ff][gG]|0[146])(?=.{10}$)|(?:05|[pP][Tt])(?=.{11}$))[0-9]*(?:[Ff][rR])?$`](https://regex101.com/r/xx02kT/3) will work exactly as you need.

Comment: big thnx Wiktor Stribiżew - everythings works fine but ,if i will  have code that starts with three symbols like  KLM07489869FR--length 13,how can i add it to your regex?we are going to add this code later.ofc i am trying by myself but i dont want to mess all your good stuff.

Comment: Let me post, I will explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?:(?:[Ff][gG]|0[146])(?=.{10}$)|(?:05|[pP][Tt])(?=.{11}$))[0-9]*(?:[Ff][rR])?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xx02kT/3).

**Explanation**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` -  start of a non-capturing alternation group

  - `(?:[Ff][gG]|0[146])` - either an `fg`, `Fg`, `fG` or `FG` sequence or `0` followed with `1`, `4` or `6`
  - `(?=.{10}$)` - a positive lookahead that requires any 10 more chars immediately to the right of the current location (10 is used because `FG` or `01` already take 2 chars  making 12 in total)
  - `|` - or
  - `(?:05|[pP][Tt])` - `05`, `pt`, `Pt`, `pT` or `PT`
  - `(?=.{11}$)` - a positive lookahead that requires any 11 more chars immediately to the right of the current location
- `)` - end of the alternation group
- `[0-9]*` - 0+ digits
- `(?:[Ff][rR])?` - an optional sequence (1 or 0 times), `fr`, `Fr`, `fR` or `FR`
- `$` - end of string.

Now, adding `KLM07489869FR` format support (`KLM` is 3 char long, thus the rest must be 10, so we place the `KLM` matching part to the alternative with `(?=.{10}$)`):

```
^(?:(?:[Ff][gG]|0[146]|[Kk][Ll][Mm])(?=.{10}$)|(?:05|[pP][Tt])(?=.{11}$))[0-9]*(?:[Ff][rR])?$
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```